# Is it possible to redirect to an Action method from a class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC5 Application I want to redirect to an action method from a class as following

```
  public static User GetUserObject()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] != null)
        {
            User currentUser = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] as User;

            return currentUser;
        }
        else
        {
            //I want to redirect to the login action method from here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to simply do this from the caller (action): `var usr = GetUserObject(); if (usr == null) { //do redirect } else { //I am a currentUser! }`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, But it's not recommended:

```
else {
    var context = new RequestContext(
    new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current),
    new RouteData());
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context);
    var url = urlHelper.Action("About", "Home");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
    return new User();
}
```

I think it would be better to do this way:

```
public static User GetUserObject()
{
     return HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] as User;
}
```

Then inside your action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userObject = Helpers.Helper.GetUserObject();
    if (userObject == null)
         return RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");
    else
         return RedirectToAction("", "")

    //

}
```